# square the array element in O(n) running time

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, big-o

Is there a way to square the elements of the array with time complexity of O(n)?
I tried two ways of doing it but I think they are both O(N^2)
PS: I can't use "*", only addition/subtraction.

```
1.
#include <stdio.h>

int squr(int n, int j){
    if(j == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(j > 0)
        return(n + squr(n, j - 1));
    else if (n < 0)
        return(n + squr(n, j - 1));
}

void loop(int* arr, int count){
    for(int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        arr[n] = squr(arr[n], arr[n]);
}

2. 
void squr(int* arr, int N){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            sum += i;

        arr[i] = sum;
        sum = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do arr[i] = arr[i] * arr[i]?

Comment: or `ar[i] *= ar[i];`?

Comment: sorry, I should mention that I cannot use *.

Comment: You can emulate multiplication using simpler operations in `O(lg N)` time, but I doubt you need to do that here.  There's a major difference between your two approaches -- one squares the pre-existing value in the array, the other one ignores the pre-existing value and squares the index.  Which are you supposed to be doing (the latter can easily be done in `O(N)` total time)?

Comment: BTW your first recursive function has a flaw... for some combination of parameters you can flow off the end of a non-void function, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: You can store the result of multiplication if your arr is big you will have some duplicate computation.

Comment: Even peano arithmetic square would be done in O(n) and best case O(log n) but doing multiplication of m elements would become O(m*n) or O(m log n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not likely what OP had in mind, code can use the size of a computed pointer.  No `*`.  Of course restricted to `n > 0`.

```
int foo(int n, char a[1][n][n]) {
  return sizeof a[0];
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", foo(5, 0));
  printf("%d\n", foo(100, 0));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
25
10000
```